# how to call an API onSubmit in React and update it based on a new value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a form which needs to fetch the data onSubmit. Then it outputs the result into my UI (whether it is a positive or negative value).

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function TextArea() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [score, setScore] = useState(null);

  function fetchData() {
    fetch(
      `https://lalala-sentiment-analysis.net/sentiment?message=${text}`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setScore(data.score));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetchData();
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    setText(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Essay:</label>
        <textarea type='text' value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type='submit' value='submit' />
      </form>
      <p>{score}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default TextArea;
```

So I'm used to useEffect() when I fetch the data, but it seems like I don't need it here. Or at least I'm not sure. And second thing, I can't fetched the data after the first fetch. If I type in another text in my input, it doesn't output a new score below.

How to solve it and what would be the best coding practice for this case?

Comment: You don't need useEffect here since you just want to get the data when clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to fetch the data initially after Component render in `useEffect()` at all because you want the data on form submit. So, remove the `useEffect()` function :)

And then while rendering `score`, you have to show it only once the data is available.You can use this `&&` operator (provided `score` is not an object but a value otherwise, you need to use `dot` operator to render the value from the object like `score.value` [something like this])

```
<p>{score && score}</p>
```

I also feel you should use a `catch` block and add a state for failure case:

Something like :
const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

And in the function

```
  function fetchData() {
    fetch(
      `https://lalala-sentiment-analysis.net/sentiment?message=${text}`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setScore(data.score))
      .catch(()=>{
         setIsError(true);
      })
}
```

And in JSX below `<p>` tag:

```
 <p> {isError && "Could not fetch the Data"}</p>
```

Comment: Hi Imran, thanks for your reply. To be honest, I'm confused with what you said. I already access the value of the score in the API call when setting it setScore(data.score). And if I were to update it then, it doesn't work. Could you show how the code with look like in your opinion?

Comment: `setScore(data.score)` is invoked twice in your case, You only need it once you submit the form. So, initially you simple need to delete `useEffect()`.

Comment: @yavnelf I am occupied with work a lot these days. Let's connect tomorrow on this. You can create a codesandbox.io project for this and I will have a look and get to know your Acceptance Criteria as well. 
Don't worry.

Comment: I already found out the answer, I basically had to use useCallback()

Comment: OK :) Keep it up